# How to create shape keys from posing armature?

Tags: rigging

I have one character with his face rigged and I want create shape keys from posing bones of his face, I'm trying to do this with the armature modifier but when I make clic in Apply as shape key, this create the shape key but my armature unlink of my mesh, so I copied the modifier before apply as shape key, but the pose doesnt back to original pose. Is there another method to do this or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the pose you want
2. In the armature modifier **save** as shape key (previous versions of Blender require *apply* followed by recreation of the modifier).
3. Go to the object data tab and rename the new shape key (it will be named after your armature).

In this way you will have the mesh controlled by the armature and a shape key which will reflect the pose you set in point 1)

Comment: @Ben Jackson Formatting is a fine edit, but I think your answer is significantly different from the one here and deserves to be its own answer to the question, and so I have to reject your edit.